# Remove scroll ability from GtkSpinButton

Tags: gtk

I find that GtkSpinButton can be useful for controlled input numbers on GTK GUI.
But here are some nice features of GTK button which can be unwanted in many cases.
If we have GtkSpinButton inside scrolledwindow then user can accidentally change value, or GtkSpinButton can take scroll behaviour from scrolledwindow.

Question: Is here any possibility to make GtkScrollButton insensible to mouse wheel, at way like is GtkEntry. Or better, could GtkSpinButton be shown without up/down buttons.
If not, how to redirect scroll signal from GtkSpinButton to scrolledwindow?

I try this:

```
SCROLL_numgreen (GtkObject *object, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
{
switch (((GdkEventScroll *)event)->direction)
{
case GDK_SCROLL_UP:
    return TRUE;
    break;

case GDK_SCROLL_DOWN:
    return TRUE;
    break;

... etc...
```

but this only "eats" scroll signal from GtkSpinButton and block scrolledwindow at place.
I would most like some general solution without intervention to events of every GtkSpinButton.

Answer (score 7):

Here a few pointers to your queries:

*`Is here any possibility to make GtkScrollButton insensible to mouse wheel, at way like is GtkEntry?`*
Mouse wheel scroll, mouse click are  *events*. The events can be masked. This can be done at two levels.

1. At `GtkWidget` level: you can use [`gtk_widget_get_events()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-events) which will return the event mask in the form of [`GdkEventMask`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Events.html#GdkEventMask). You can modify this as per your need & set it using [`gtk_widget_set_events()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-events)
2. At `GdkWindow` level: `GtkWidget` which has its own drawing/eventing area has a [`GdkWindow`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html) associated with it. You can get the event mask of this window using [`gdk_window_get_events()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-get-events) and change returned [`GdkEventMask`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Events.html#GdkEventMask) as per your need & set it to the `GdkWindow` using [`gdk_window_set_events()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-events). You can modify event mask through bit-wise operations. If `GdkWindow` is shared between more than one widget then this mask will effect all the widgets. For masking scroll events you can look into `GDK_SCROLL_MASK`, `GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK` & `GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK`. You can always check the mask for the event which you are looking for is already set or not. **Note**: `GdkWindow` related calls will succeed only after `GdkWindow` is created for `GtkWidget`. You can make these calls after `gtk_widget_show()` of the widget or `gtk_widget_show_all` of the window which contains these widgets.

*`Or better, could GtkSpinButton be shown without up/down buttons.`*
AFAIK `GtkSpinButton` is implemented to have up/down button indicative of the functionality it provides. If you don't want this, then you can choose another widget say `GtkEntry` (from which `GtkSpinButton` is "*derived*") or `GtkLabel`. Of course you can create your own widget (from scratch or "*derive*" from an existing `GtkWidget`) as per your need & use that same; there is no one stopping you from doing this :)

*`How to redirect scroll signal from GtkSpinButton to scrolledwindow?`*
It is possible to do this in the `"scroll-event"` callback of GtkSpinButton. You can stop the emission of the signal on `GtkSpinButton` & return `FALSE` to propagate the event.

```
...
/* Event callback */
gboolean spinbutton_scroll_handler(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event,  gpointer   user_data)
{
    /* Stop emission on current widget. Default handler also not called */
    /* Refer http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-stop-emission-by-name */
    g_signal_stop_emission_by_name(widget, "scroll-event");
    /* Return FALSE to propagate the event further; thus scroll window will scroll
       If TRUE returned other handlers not invoked for this event, 
       thus no scroll on scroll window  */
    return FALSE;
}
...
/* Connect scroll-event to the callback */
g_signal_connect(spinbutton, "scroll-event", 
                 G_CALLBACK(spinbutton_scroll_handler),
                 (gpointer)0);
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. g_signal_stop_emission_by_name(widget, "scroll-event"); solves all problems regarding scroll issues on GtkSpinButton and GtkComboBox too. This Gtk is really amazing! I'm trying to make custom widget ;) and I have it on Glade but I can't get them on compiled program. From this point I'm very close!

Comment: I dont know if this kind updating of questions is allowed but it is close to main theme and I should to try. g_signal_stop_emission_by_name works nice on gtkSpinButtons but don't work as expected on gtkTextView and gtkTreeView. Can I do here something (easy) that gtkTextView will not accept mouse scroll and that gtkScrolledWindow in back would behave like gtkTextView is not present.

Comment: @user973238: Extremely sorry about late response. I will check this, I am not very sure.

Comment: Please check, I still don't move forward with this. With your first help on GtkSpinButton i added switch "controlpressed" like this: if (!ctrlpressed) g_signal_stop_emission_by_name(GTK_WIDGET(object), "scroll-event"); so I have both ways of working depends on ctrl key pressed. I would like to get same with GtkTextView and TreeView. When ctrl is pressed I would like to scroll TextView, when released ScrollWindow. Is this possible?

Comment: @user973238: Could you provide more info regarding how you are packing etc (some piece of code if possible)? Textview seems to be fine on the system I'm checking. Try [this code](http://pastebin.com/8MMKZk0T). I am able to scroll using the mouse wheel even when the focus is in text view using gtk+ 2.24.7

Comment: My Gtk is 2.24.6, Linux Ubuntu 11.10. Code is this: <begin code>G_MODULE_EXPORT gboolean
SCROLL_txtv_mytextview(GtkObject *object, GdkEvent *event,  gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print("SCROLL_txtv_mytextview\n");
    if (!ctrlpressed) g_signal_stop_emission_by_name(GTK_WIDGET(object), "scroll-event");
    return FALSE;
} <End code> Widget is properly referenced and event raised as expected (I see through g_print). Packings are done in glade. I think also properly and This is big xml file unsuitable to post here.

Comment: Hm, by studying your code (which works well) I found my mistake!! I placed mytextview in additional scrolledwindow to be able to scroll in case of big text. Error was in this that I watch for scroll event on textview instead on his scrolled window! Now this work as expected and also "ctrlpressed mode" works well. I suppose that same problem is with treeview :) Thank you very much for your additional and very valuable help in my learning of gtk!!

Comment: @user973238: Glad to help! Good to know that you got it right and thats what matters :)

Comment: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#stop-using-gtkwidget-event-signals

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could do that in GTK4.

```
/* No-op to prevent @w from propagating "scroll" events it receives.
 */
void disable_scroll_cb( GtkWidget *w ) {}

/* Disable scroll on a widget by adding a capture phase event handler and
 * connecting a no-op callback to the "scroll" event.
 */
static GtkWidget *
disable_scroll( GtkWidget *w )
{
        GtkEventController *ec;

        ec = gtk_event_controller_scroll_new(
                        GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER_SCROLL_VERTICAL );

        gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase( ec, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE );
        g_signal_connect( ec, "scroll", G_CALLBACK( disable_scroll_cb ), w );
        gtk_widget_add_controller( w, ec );

        return w;
}

/* Create a spin button with range, default value, and optionally enabled
 * scrolling.
 */
GtkWidget *
create_spin_button( double min, double max, double step,
                double value, bool scroll )
{
        GtkWidget *sb;

        sb = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range( min, max, step );
        gtk_spin_button_set_value( GTK_SPIN_BUTTON( sb ), value );

        return scroll ? sb : disable_scroll( sb );
}
```

Comment: GtkScale example https://stackoverflow.com/a/77268812