# How to disable scrollwheel on Gtk Scale widget

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I would like to disable the scrollwheel on the Scale widget in Gtk. I am using Gtk with python. I am aware of the `disconnect` function. However, I don't have the function handler id since I did not connect the scrollwheel to the Scale widget, which is done by default.

Is there a way I can disable the scrollwheel from changing the values of the scale.

```
import gi
gi.require_version( 'Gtk', '3.0' )
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(200,200)
scale = Gtk.HScale.new_with_range( 0, 1, 0.01 )

window.add(scale)


window.connect( 'delete-event', Gtk.main_quit )
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I have connected the following two signals to determine which one is responsible for the scroll wheel changing the value.

```
scale.connect(  'change-value', test_change_value )
scale.connect( 'value-changed', test_value_changed )
```

```
def test_change_value( widget, scroll_type, scroll_value ):
    print(scroll_type)
    return True

def test_value_changed( widget ):
    return True
```

Since both functions return `True` any other function connected to the same event will be ignored. I find that when only `'change-value'` is connected the scroll wheel does not effect the value of the scale, which I believe means that the default connection to `'change-value'` is no longer being called. However, the default connection is also not called when I drag the knob on the scale, which is a feature I still want. Maybe there is a way for me to only `return True` if the `scroll_type` indicates the scroll is caused by the mouse wheel. Or maybe I am going down the wrong route and there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C/GTK4 example.

```
/* No-op to prevent @w from propagating "scroll" events it receives.
 */
void disable_scroll_cb( GtkWidget *w ) {}

/* Disable scroll on a widget by adding a capture phase event handler and
 * connecting a no-op callback to the "scroll" event.
 */
static GtkWidget *
disable_scroll( GtkWidget *w )
{
        GtkEventController *ec;

        ec = gtk_event_controller_scroll_new(
                        GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER_SCROLL_VERTICAL );

        gtk_event_controller_set_propagation_phase( ec, GTK_PHASE_CAPTURE );
        g_signal_connect( ec, "scroll", G_CALLBACK( disable_scroll_cb ), w );
        gtk_widget_add_controller( w, ec );

        return w;
}

/* Create a spin button with range, default value, and optionally enabled
 * scrolling.
 */
GtkWidget *
create_scale( double min, double max, double step,
                double value, bool scroll )
{
        GtkWidget *s;

        s = gtk_scale_new_with_range( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, min, max, step );
        gtk_range_set_value( GTK_RANGE( s ), value );

        return scroll ? s : disable_scroll( s );
}
```

Comment: GtkSpinButton example https://stackoverflow.com/a/77268742/15347182

Answer (score 0):

I went down the route of connecting a new `'scroll-event'` to the `HScale` widget, then having the callback function `return True`. This allowed me to disable the scroll wheel on the Scale widget.

I did this by adding the following code.

```
def disable_scroll( *args ):
    return True
scale.connect(  'change-value', disable_scroll )
```

Comment: Great solution in GTK3, unfortunately deprecated now  https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#stop-using-gtkwidget-event-signals